# How to map JSON data in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, loops

I want to display a list of icons like [this website](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/).

I have JSON data that stores the `family` and the `name` of the icons. I want to map the JSON to pass the family value and the name value in my component `CardItem`.

However, I don't know how to map it correctly. Thanks for your help!

```
import React from "react";
import { CardItem } from "./card";

export const List = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      family: "AntDesign",
      names: ["stepforward", "stepbackward", "forward", "banckward"]
    },
    {
      family: "Entypo",
      names: ["500px", "500px-with-circle", "add-to-list", "add-user"]
    }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {data.map((data, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <CardItem
              family={data.family}
              name={data.names.map((name) => name)}
            />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: `data.names.map((name) => name )` won't do anything, you should use `data.names`

Comment: Do you want a `CardItem` element by name (meaning merging the two sub-arrays) or a `CardItem` by first level items?

Comment: @MetallimaX I want a CardItem by name :)

Comment: `data.names.map(name) => <CardItem key={name} name={name} />`

Comment: I don't think that nesting the `map` will behave well as the result will be a list of lists.

Comment: `<><ul>...</ul></>` is an anti-pattern. `<>...</>` creates a fragment and is not needed when there's is only _one_ node, such as `ul` here. use `<>...</>` when you are returning more than one node, such as `<><p>paragraph 1</p><p>paragraph 2</p></>`.

Comment: it is not recommended to use array indexes for keys. Read [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) from the React docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to, you could try to reverse-engineer the DOM on that website. Here is the general flow of the DOM on that site:

### Files:

- App.jsx

  - icon_data.json
  - ResultContainer.jsx

    - ResultRow.jsx

      - ResultTitle.jsx
      - ResultList.jsx

        - ResultIcon.jsx

Here is a forkable snippet of the code below:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/react-icon-mapping-qfsp5?file=/src/App.jsx

### icon_data.json

```json
[
  {
    "family": "AntDesign",
    "names": ["stepforward", "stepbackward", "forward", "backward"]
  },
  {
    "family": "Entypo",
    "names": ["500px", "500px-with-circle", "add-to-list", "add-user"]
  }
]
```

### App.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import iconData from "./icon_data.json";
import ResultContainer from "./ResultContainer";

const fetchIconData = () => Promise.resolve(() => iconData);

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchIconData().then((jsonData) => setData(jsonData));
  }, []);

  return <ResultContainer data={data} />;
};

export default App;
```

### ResultContainer.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import ResultRow from "./ResultRow";

const ResultContainer = (props) => {
  const { data } = props;

  return (
    <>
      {data.map(({ family, names }) => {
        return <ResultRow title={family} icons={names} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
};

ResultContainer.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default ResultContainer;
```

### ResultRow.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import ResultTitle from "./ResultTitle";
import ResultList from "./ResultList";

const ResultRow = (props) => {
  const { title, icons } = props;

  return (
    <div className="Result-Row">
      <ResultTitle title={title} />
      <ResultList icons={icons} />
    </div>
  );
};

ResultTitle.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  icons: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default ResultRow;
```

### ResultTitle

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const style = {
  background: "#F66667",
  color: "#FFFFFF",
  padding: "1em",
  margin: "0"
};

const ResultTitle = (props) => {
  const { title } = props;

  return (
    <h2 className="Result-Title" style={style}>
      {title}
    </h2>
  );
};

ResultTitle.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default ResultTitle;
```

### ResultList.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import ResultIcon from "./ResultIcon";

const style = {
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "row"
};

const ResultList = (props) => {
  const { icons } = props;

  return (
    <div className="Result-List" style={style}>
      {icons.map((icon) => (
        <ResultIcon name={icon} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

ResultList.propTypes = {
  icons: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default ResultList;
```

### ResultIcon.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const containerStyle = {
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "column",
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: "center",
  padding: "0.5em",
  outline: "thin solid rgb(238, 238, 238)"
};

const iconStyle = {
  fontWeight: "normal",
  fontSize: "2em",
  textAlign: "center"
};

const titleStyle = {
  fontSize: "smaller",
  fontWeight: "normal",
  textAlign: "center",
  margin: "0"
};

const ResultIcon = (props) => {
  const { name } = props;

  return (
    <div className="Result-Icon-Container" style={containerStyle}>
      <span className="Result-Icon" style={iconStyle}>
        ☺
      </span>
      <h4 className="Result-Icon-Name" style={titleStyle}>
        {name}
      </h4>
    </div>
  );
};

ResultIcon.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default ResultIcon;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

```
import React from "react";
import { CardItem } from "./card";

export const List = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      family: "AntDesign",
      names: ["stepforward", "stepbackward", "forward", "banckward"]
    },
    {
      family: "Entypo",
      names: ["500px", "500px-with-circle", "add-to-list", "add-user"]
    }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            {item.names.map((name) => {
               return <CardItem
                    family={item.family}
                    name={name}
            />

            })
            }
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!

Comment: [Don't use index as keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) You have a perfectly good key with `item.family`, and you also forgot to put a key (name) on the inner array.